# casting from and to composite types in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, composite

I have created a composite type in postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE mytimestamp AS (t timestamp with time zone, o int);
```

and added it to a table

```
CREATE TABLE t (t0 mytimestamp)
```

Using a custom conversion function and the following CAST, I was able to convert a simple timestamp with time zone into a 'mytimestamp' in an INSERT statement:

```
CREATE CAST (timestamp with time zone AS mytimestamp) 
WITH FUNCTION to_mytimestamp(timestamp with time zone) AS ASSIGNMENT;

INSERT INTO t (t0) VALUES(now()); -- works as intended
```

However, I cannot seem to create a CAST that works with the following statement:

```
CREATE CAST (varchar AS mytimestamp) 
WITH FUNCTION to_mytimestamp(varchar) AS ASSIGNMENT;

INSERT INTO t (t0) 
VALUES('2014-09-11 13:30:12.564+02'); -- returns 'malformed record literal'
```

(I'd need a conversion from varchar, char or text - but simply implementing the conversion function and adding the respective CAST doesn't seem to work)

I know I could achieve this by altering the query to

```
INSERT INTO t (t0) 
VALUES('2014-09-11 13:30:12.564+02'::varchar); -- works
-- the to_mytimestamp(varchar) function is called
```

However in my case, I can't change the queries since they're defined in some code that shouldn't be changed anymore.

Is there a way for me to ensure the `to_mytimestamp(varchar)` function is called when executing the above INSERT statement (without having to append `::varchar`)?

Thanks a bunch!

---

edit: 
Here are the mentioned functions (replace `text` with `varchar` or `char` in `to_mytimestamp()` as needed):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_mytimestamp(t text)
  RETURNS mytimestamp AS
$BODY$
declare
ts mytimestamp;
offs text;
matches text[];
begin

 offs = substr(t, length(t) - 5, 6);
 matches = regexp_matches(offs, '[+-][0-9.:]*', 'g');
 offs = split_part(matches[1], ':', 1)::integer * 3600 + split_part(matches[1], ':', 2)::integer * 60;
 ts.t = t::timestamp with time zone;
 ts.o = offs;
 return ts;

end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_mytimestamp(t timestamp with time zone)
  RETURNS mytimestamp AS
' select $1, extract(timezone from $1) '
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

explanation: the functions extract the utc offset and store it in a separate value for later reconstruction.
note: `to_mytimestamp(t timestamp with time zone)` stores the system offset, not the one one would assume is stored in the argument `t`, since timestamp with time zone doesn't actually contain offset data - but this is irrelevant to the problem :)

Comment: Can you post the to_mytimestamp() functions for varchar and  timestamp with time zone?  I'd like to take a stab at figuring this out !

Comment: Done. I've added implementations for to_mytimestamp() for both 'text' and 'timestamp with time zone'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

When you write a string literal `'foo'` in postgres, it actually has an "unknown" type, rather than text. Thus, your cast function does not match because the types differ. This is why you can do:

```
SELECT '2014-09-11 13:30:12.564+02'::text::mytimestamp;
```

and it will work as expected.

Even if you write a version of the function that handles `unknown` as the parameter type (and converts this to `text` first), and create the relevant cast:

```
CREATE CAST (unknown AS mytimestamp) 
WITH FUNCTION mytimestamp(unknown) 
AS IMPLICIT;
```

Postgres will still try to use the original composite type conversion function. Indeed, this breaks the "convert-to-text-first" path, because there is no better match for `mytimestamp(text)`, so it uses the in-built function.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to test because the to_mytimestamp() function is missing.  But, could this be as simple as:

```
CREATE CAST (text AS mytimestamp) 
WITH FUNCTION to_mytimestamp(text) AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

?
-g

Comment: unfortunately not - I tried to create casts for text, varchar and char. None of them seems to get picked when trying to insert string literals.

Comment: This cast works, but only if casting from an existing `text` value. Since untyped literals are `unknown`, it won't cast correctly. Instead, it tries to use the `COMPOSITE TYPE` casting.